# Подключение к postgresql через SSH Tunnel

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Есть база данных [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) на удаленном сервере. Из pgAdmin я подключаюсь к этой бд только через ssh tunnel.

Можно ли как-то подключиться к бд в nodejs?

Как сделать proxy или во что обернуть этот код?

```
const {Pool, Client} = require('pg');

let pg = {
  connection: new Pool({
    user: 'dbuser',
    host: 'dbhost',
    database: 'postgres',
    password: 'dbpass',
    port: 5432,
  }),

  selectEmail: function (email) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const str = `SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE "email" = '${email}'`;
      this.connection.query(str, (err, res) => {
        if (res) {
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      });
    });
  },

};

module.exports = pg;
```

Comment: я обычно включал туннель в соседней консоли. но вообще, вроде, нет проблем завернуть ваш скрипт в npmjs.com/package/tunnel-ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Подключение к базе данных postgresql на удалённом сервере с использованием ssh-туннеля

Код полностью рабочий, проверен на macOS Mojave, node.js v14.13.0, драйвер [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) v8.4.0, библиотека [tunnel-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel-ssh) v4.1.4.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const tunnelSsh = require('tunnel-ssh');
const { Pool } = require('pg');

(async () => {

  /** @type {import('net').Server} */
  let tunnel;
  try {
    tunnel = await createTunnel();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  try {
    const db = connectPg();
    const { rows } = await db.query('select now()');
    console.log(rows); // [ { now: 2020-10-13T22:08:50.496Z } ]
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    tunnel.close();
  }

})();


/**
 * @param {number} [localPort=63334]
 * @returns {Promise<import('net').Server>}
 */
async function createTunnel(localPort = 63334) {

  /** @type {import('tunnel-ssh').Config} */
  const tunnelConfig = {
    username: 'имя пользователя на удалённом сервере',
    password: 'пароль пользователя на удалённом сервере',
    // в случае если настроен доступ по ключу
    // privateKey: fs.readFileSync(`${os.homedir()}/.ssh/id_rsa`),
    host: 'адрес удалённого сервера',
    port: 22, // порт для ssh-соединения
    dstPort: 5432, // порт postgres на удалённом сервере
    localPort: localPort, // порт postgres на локальной машине
    keepAlive: true,
    readyTimeout: 10000,
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    tunnelSsh(tunnelConfig, (err, server) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(server);
    })
    .on('error', (err) => console.error('[tunnel-ssh] error:', err))
    .on('connection', () => console.log('[tunnel-ssh] connected'))
    .on('close', () => console.log('[tunnel-ssh] closed'));

  });
}

/**
 * @param {number} [localPort=63334]
 * @returns {import('pg').Pool}
 */
function connectPg(localPort = 63334) {

  /** @type {import('pg').ConnectionConfig} */
  const connectionConfig = {
    database: 'db_name',
    port: localPort, // порт, куда туннель проксирует postgres
    user: 'db_user_name',
    password: 'db_user_password'
  };

  return new Pool(connectionConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

вы можете использовать пакет SSH, чтобы открыть туннель из Node.js

Например, эта ссылка: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel-ssh

Когда туннель открыт, вы подключаетесь к БД, как если бы она была локальной.

Например, как показано здесь: https://medium.com/@dannibla/connecting-nodejs-postgresql-f8967b9f5932